# AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute 'create_login_url'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a question on google app engine. I copied this code directly from Google App Engine but somehow it did not work as expected. It always gave me the error :

```
self.redirect(self.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute 'create_login_url'
```

What does this mean?

Below is my code

```
from google.appengine.api import users

import webapp2


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    # [START get_current_user]
    # Checks for active Google account session
    user = users.get_current_user()
    # [END get_current_user]

    # [START if_user]
    if user:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
    # [END if_user]
    # [START if_not_user]
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
    # [END if_not_user]


  application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
 ], debug=True)



=============================================================================================

 and my app.yaml
 application: your-app-id
 version: 1
 runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
 - url: /.*
 script: helloworld.application
```

Comment: Your traceback contains the line `self.redirect(self.create_login_url(self.request.uri))`, but your code contains the *different* line `self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))` (`self` changed to `users`). Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation looks off. Make sure the line `def get(self):` is indented more than the line `class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):`

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage),
        ], debug=True)
```